# Create directory inside NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: iphone, temporary-files, temporary-directory

How can I create a directory inside `NSTemporaryDirectory`? I tried something like:

```
[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myTmp/"];
```

followed by the file name, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `NSFileManager` to create the directory for you:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myTmp/"] 
    withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Just a small comment: this method has to be used with an instance of NSFileManager.

Comment: Do you know how could I create the directory with the permissions drwx------? I've been trying, but I always get a different permission.