# low resolution preview image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a bunch of large 360 degree image sequences that are color corrected and flipping through the rotation is really choppy.  I could add a low res version and swap it out, but it seems some apps do this automatically (I'm not sure if it's PDFs or Photos), I'm not sure if it's reading embedded thumbnail data or what is going on.

Most images are 1.5MB and the client insists on using the approved, color corrected images but it open to swapping from low to high res, there are thousands of images and I don't want to bloat the app bundle any more as it is a considerable size now.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How are you displaying the images?  What does “flipping through the rotation” mean?

Comment: Spinning an object in x-y-z rotations through a progression of 3d renders that are PNG images.  There are 150 images per lighting conditions, 3 lighting conditions per item. It is controlled with a UISlider with values 1-150, on value change the image is loaded into an NSData object and then loaded into a UIImageView.  If I load the image directly using imageNamed: there are memory warnings immediately so I do the data, imageWithData route.  This system worked well with lower res JPGs before I received the final images from the client.

Comment: What are these pictures of?  Are you sure PNG is the appropriate format?

Comment: The client specified they must be loss-less, color corrected images and supplied them, they are renders of their products.

Answer (score 0):

If the lag is caused by the loading process, then you will have to load and display the thumbnails instead of the large images. You may want to create the thumbnails programmatically on first app launch by downsizing the images once and store it in a [temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847788/create-directory-inside-nstemporarydirectory) on the users device. This will not increase the size of the bundle.

If the lag is caused because of the frequent displaying of the large images, you can [programmatically resize](http://www.sourcedrop.net/3vP43a1dec4c7) them to the correct size and store them in an [in-memory cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html).